# Rank rows from table and save ranking on another table with date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with game scores: user_id, user_name, game_score

I would like to rank the users by game_score and then save the rank of each user in the ranking table with today's date.

I can select all the rows from the table:

```
SELECT game_score, user_id, user_name FROM scores ORDER BY game_score DESC
```

And then run a query to save each user to the ranking table

```
INSERT INTO ranking_table (user_id, user_rank, today) VALUES ($user_id, $user_rank, $today)
```

But, if I have 500 players, that's 500 queries.

Is there a way to make it the process with fewer queries?

Comment: Have you tried RANK()?

Comment: This must be solved by ONE query.

Comment: Presumably you're storing the rank because you think it's too large a dataset to calculate 'on-the-fly'?

Comment: Because I would like to show the ranking of the user by day. e.g. on 9/25 your ranking was #34, on 9/26 #32, on 9/27 #5

Comment: Well there's no reason why you can't just calculate that on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO ranking_table (user_id, user_rank, today)
WITH cte AS (SELECT user_id, 
                    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY game_score DESC) user_rank
             FROM scores)
SELECT user_id, 
       user_rank, 
       CURRENT_DATE
FROM cte;
```